# How should the fields be ordered in a sitemap when including hreflang?

Tags: xml-sitemap, internationalization, hreflang, change-frequency, last-modified

I have a website with multiple languages and version for different countries. However it is all using the same domain and segregated by locale query parameter. Examples as below:

- `example.com` is the general domain
- `example.com?lang=ZH_SG` (Chinese language users in Singapore)
- `example.com/?lang=en_SG` (English language users in Singapore)
- `example.com/?lang=en_MY` (English language users in Malaysia)
- `example.com/?lang=ms_MY` (Malay language users in Malaysia)

As far as I understand it, you should include the locale query parameter in the sitemap. However what about the typical sitemap requirements like (`lastmod`, `priority`, `changefreq`)?

1. Do you include `lastmod`, `priority`, `changefreq` in the `hreflang` sitemap together with the `hreflang`?
2. If you do, do you place it before the `hreflang`? Any samples to refer to?

Answer (score 1):

1. lastmod, priority, changefreq  can be omitted.
2. Include your hreflang urls according to the following example:

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" 
       xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
       <url>
       <loc>http://www.example.com/english/</loc>
       <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://www.example.com/deutsch/" />
       <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-ch" href="http://www.example.com/schweiz-deutsch/" />
       <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.example.com/english/" />
       </url>
       <url>
       <loc>http://www.example.com/deutsch/</loc>
       <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-ch" href="http://www.example.com/schweiz-deutsch/" />
       <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.example.com/english/" />
       <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://www.example.com/deutsch/" />
       </url>
       <loc>http://www.example.com/schweiz-deutsch/</loc>
       <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.example.com/english/" />
       <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://www.example.com/deutsch/" />
       <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-ch" href="http://www.example.com/schweiz-deutsch/" />
       </url>
       </urlset>`

Remember: every url must reference to each other.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply.
What if i have a mobile version abc.com/m/ ?
Do I need to include it inside my sitemap too?

Comment: No, because a mobile version did on this way is duplicated content and should be deindexed. It isn't allowed to include deindexed pages into sitemap.